# Coq: Boolean Comparison of Integers

Tags: coq

The natural numbers (nat) in coq have a function beq_nat, is there a similar function for integers Z (in ZArith)?

And for the future, how can I find the answer to such questions without asking on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the `Z.eqb` function in the standard library. Make sure to import module `ZArith` tp use it.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any resources for finding this besides browsing the [standard library](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/) documentation...